# Sorted Range of uncertain size.

Tags: excel, sorting

My goal for the coding below is to select and sort a range of unknown length that is between rows that should not be sorted.

I want the sorting variable to be column P

B3 will always be the upper left hand corner of my range.

The P column will always be the right hand boundary of my range.

I know that an alternative method would be use a variable that equals the length of the range but it would be much simpler to use the selected cell as the bottom right boundary.

I see two problems with the code below. Row 9 identifies the range as "P2:P300" and this happens again in row 12, but I can't use "Activecell" since the proper cell isn't active at this point in the code.

Any suggestions?    Apologies for the sloppy/unnecessary code at points, I've been stealing liberally off of these forums.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

    ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Select
    ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, "B3").Select  ''''''Selects last cell in range

   '''Following should sort selected range according to the values in the "P" column

     ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("P2:P300") _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort
            .SetRange Range("B1:P300")
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With    

End Sub
```

Comment: You have defined the upper left hand and the upper right had boundary. What about the lower left/right boundary? What will help decide that?

Comment: Its uncertain because the size of the data set varies. Initially I find the boundary with the first three lines of code.

Comment: My real question is, "Once you've selected the range in question, how do you sort only that range with a macro?"

Comment: Solved.       here's the code:   ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Select
ActiveCell.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Select
Range(ActiveCell, "B3").Select

With ActiveSheet.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Selection.Columns(15), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Selection
    .Apply
End With         '''Good explanation here: http://p2p.wrox.com/excel-vba/83377-use-macro-sort-user-selected-range.html

Comment: rng.Sort Key1:=ws1.Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal